# How to store from a Gtk.Entry() as a variable, and then for example *10 and put the new value in a Gtk.Label() , in python3 using PyGObject?(PyGtk)

Tags: python, gtk3, pygobject

So I write the number in the entry and when I press the button, in label should appear my value multiplied by 10. But in return I have this error when I press the button: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_text'.
I don't know how to make it. Please help :(

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class EntryWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Entry Demo")
        self.set_default_size(200, 100)
        
        grid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.add(grid)        
        
        self.entry1 = Gtk.Entry()
        self.entry1.set_activates_default(True)        
        
        self.t1 = Gtk.Label()
        
        button = Gtk.Button(label="CALC")
        button.connect("clicked", self.calc)
        
        grid.attach(self.entry1, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        grid.attach(self.t1, 1,2,1,1)
        grid.attach(button, 2,1,1,1)
        
    def calc(self, widget, data=None):
        port = self.entry1.get_text() 
        
        a = float(port.get_text())*10
        self.t1.set_text(" " + a.get_text())
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done it. I don't know if is it the best solutions, but this is it: (if someone have a better solution, I am all ears)
def **init**(self):
        Gtk.Window.**init**(self, title="Change Label Text")

```
    table = Gtk.Table(3, 3, True)
    self.add(table)

    adjustment = Gtk.Adjustment(0, 0, 100, 1, 10, 0)
    self.spinbutton = Gtk.SpinButton()
    self.spinbutton.set_adjustment(adjustment)

    self.label = Gtk.Label("Press the button")
    button = Gtk.Button("Press Me")
    button.connect("clicked", self.button_pressed)

    table.attach(self.label, 1, 2, 0, 1)
    table.attach(button, 1, 2, 1, 2)
    table.attach(self.spinbutton, 1, 2 ,2 ,3)

def button_pressed(self, button):
    port = self.spinbutton.get_value()

    self.label.set_text(str(int(port)*10))
```